# openssl PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Tags: ssl-certificate, centos7, openssl, godaddy, tomcat8

Very new to SSL installation in Tomcat 8.5. OS: CentOS 7

I have SSL certificates from GoDaddy and have the private key used to generate the certificates.
This private key was shared in a .txt file and I copied it into a .key file to distinguish it from other files. It is stored in a file **sitename.com.key**

In a bundle from GoDaddy downloaded for Tomcat following files are present

1. *a-hash-code*.crt
2. *a-hash-code*.pem
3. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
4. gdig2.crt.pem

Going through Tomcat 8.5 documentation and other guides I have done the following steps to create a keystore and import certificates into the keystore.

> 1. sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file
>    gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore keystore-name.keystore

> 2. sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file *a-hash-code*.crt -keystore keystore-name.keystore

Importing Private Key into the Keystore

> 3. sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -name servercert -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -inkey sitename.com.key -out p12keystore.12

This step 3 throws error in terminal

> unable to load private key
>
> 140041401685904:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Private Key file is of the following format

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> Hash
>
> -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Checked key file mime type and it shows UTF8.

> $ file -i sitename.com.key
>
> sitename.com.key: text/plain; charset=utf-8

OpenSSL Version

> OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)

What is the problem here?